# Move a .csv file with an unknown file name

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to move and rename a .csv file from one folder to another using PowerShell on a daily basis. The .csv file will have a different file name each day but will always be similar to 'Course Completion_123456_1.csv'

I'm new to Powershell and can work out how to move and rename a file with a known name using the following code;

```
Move-Item c:\folder1\Course Completion_123456_1.csv c:\folder2\CourseCompletion.csv -force
```

It's the .csv file with the unknown file name that I can't figure out and I'm hoping someone can help.

Comment: What should happen tomorrow? Should the file in folder2 be overwritten?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes the file should be overwritten they next day as it'll always have the same file name.

Comment: Is there only ever the one csv file in folder1?

Comment: Yes, 1 file is placed there each day. So if I had a script that worked then that single file would be moved. And then another file would be saved in folder 1 before the script ran the next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have only one .csv file in your source folder.

Try this:

```
$csv = Get-Item "path to the source csv file\*.csv" 
$file = $csv.FullName
Move-Item $file "path to the destination folder\newfilename.csv" -Force
```